# Why does E8 F2 FF FF FF translate to call 0xFFFFFFF7?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, machine-code

Why does `E8 F2 FF FF FF` translate to `call 0xFFFFFFF7`?
I understand that `E8` is opcode for near `call` with relative displacement. So `F2 FF FF FF` is that displacement. Because it's little-endian (?) the final displacement should be `FF FF FF F2`, shouldn't it? What am I missing?

```
$ msf-nasm_shell
nasm > call 0xfffffff7
00000000  E8F2FFFFFF        call 0xfffffff7
```

Comment: The displacement is encoded relative to the end of the instruction.  Since you assembled this instruction into address 0, the end of the instruction is at address 5.  `0xfffffff2 + 5 = 0xfffffff7`.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's a relative jump (made with offsets) and not an absolute jump (made to an address), you have to include into your calculation the initial opcodes which are used to make that call.

Imagine your pointer is at location 5.
And you want to get to location 15.

The way the jump is calculated is you say 15 - 5 = 10. So you need to go up by 10.
But the call that tells it to go up by 10 also takes up a location lets say that length is 2.

5 (your pointer) + 2 (instrucation) = 7 (your new pointer).
Now your pointer is at 7 and it is told to go up by 10, if that happens you'll end up at 17 instead of 15, so to fix it you subtract the 2 which got used making that call.

`0xF7` - `0xF2` = `5`
You used `5` op codes to make that jump instruction.

Hope that makes sense now :)

Comment: *You used 5 op codes to make that jump instruction* - I think you're trying to say that `call rel32` is 5 bytes long.  That's true, but only the E8 byte is the opcode.  The other 4 bytes are the immediate displacement.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call